# Dynamically added Checkbox check event in winform c#

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have dynamically added checkboxex on the form. On checkbox checked i want to perfor some action. Below is the code am using

```
 private void GenerateSidePanelControls()
    {
        try
        {
            int topPosition = 15;
            foreach (SideMenuItem sItem in _sideMenuItemList)
            {
                CheckBox objLabel = new CheckBox();
                objLabel.Name = sItem.TagName;
                objLabel.Text = sItem.TagName;
                objLabel.Left = 15;
                objLabel.Top = topPosition;
                objLabel.Font = _normalFont;
                sidePanel.Controls.Add(objLabel);
                topPosition += 35;

                objLabel.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.SideLabel_Click);
                               }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


      private void SideLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int topPosition = 20;
        try
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            CheckBox objLabel = (CheckBox)sender;

            objLabel.Name = objLabel.ToString();
            objLabel.Font = _boldFont;
               foreach (Control ctrl in sidePanel.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is CheckBox)
                {
                    if (((CheckBox)objLabel).Checked == true)
                    {

                        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                        txt.Text = "Checked";
                        sidePanel.Controls.Add(objLabel);
                        topPosition += 25;
                    }

                }
            }
                       }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

Am getting the result before i check the checkbox at runtime. I need the action to takeplace after the checkbox is checked at runtime.

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add checkbox with CheckedCahnged Event to a Dynamic GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527908/add-checkbox-with-checkedcahnged-event-to-a-dynamic-gridview)

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? As you are iterating through all of the checkboxes, it seems there will be something wrong. Why not assign an EventHandler?

Comment: When i check the checkbox at runtime, nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the newly created TextBox :

```
 TextBox txt = new TextBox();
 txt.Text = "Checked";
 //sidePanel.Controls.Add(objLabel);
 sidePanel.Controls.Add(txt);
 topPosition += 25;
```

I answered based on your comment `When i check the checkbox at runtime, nothing happens.`

Other *notes* to be considered :

- You are looping `foreach ctrl` and not using `ctrl`. so the loop is useless.
- You could change this line

  ```
  if (((CheckBox)objLabel).Checked == true)
  ```

  to simply

  ```
  if (objLabel.Checked)
  ```